# How do I get NSTimer to restart updating a label when returning to a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I have a basic Timer app (the start of something a bit more complex) and I'm trying to allow the user to open a new view, change some settings, then return to the time screen and have the timer still ticking down.

At the moment, when the user returns to the timer screen `ViewController`, my timer is still firing and printing the time to the console, but the label has stopped updating.

How do I start the timer updating the label again?

```
class Countdown 
{
    var initial = 100
    var count = 100
    var timer: NSTimer!
    var timerRunning = false
}

var globals = Countdown()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var timer1Label: UILabel!

@IBAction func unwindSegue(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {} // Added to get rewind segue to work as recommended by Ben Sullivan

@IBAction func timer1(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    globals.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerRunning), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func timerRunning()
{
    globals.timerRunning = true
    let minutes = (globals.count / 60) % 60;
    let seconds = globals.count % 60
    print("\(minutes):\(seconds)")
    globals.count = globals.count - 1
    timer1Label.text = String("\(minutes):\(seconds)")
} 

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

At the moment, the settings view controller has nothing on it - just a button that returns the user to ViewController.

Comment: How are you going from the second view controller back to the timer controller? Are you using a regular segue?

Comment: Yes. I've ctrl+dragged from a button in IB to the `settingsViewController` and selected 'show'. Then done the same to return to `ViewController`

Comment: Ben answered your question, but as an unrelated aside, this code assumes that the timer fires every second. But you're not always guaranteed that that will happen if the app was suspended or something blocked the main thread. It's more prudent to save the start time and then calculate the difference between the current time and the start time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are performing new segue to your timer view controller. This creates a new instance of your timer view controller rather than segueing back to the original one.

First delete the segue you have setup from your second to first controller. You will then need to use an unwind segue, you can learn how to do this by following the link below. (I had the same issue as yourself recently and this is what I was provided also)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

By using the unwind segue you shouldn't need to add any additional code as the label on your original controller should still be getting updated.

Comment: Fantastic! Thankyou very much, I've been trying to get that working for hours. I did have to watch some YouTube videos too, as the documentation wasn't the most revealing. I had to add an empty IBAction to my 'home' viewcontroller and then drag to the exit icon from my button on the settingsViewController and select the empty IBAction I had created - I'll update my code accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. I hadn't done an unwind segue till someone had showed me on here either. If it's all sorted can you hit the tick to say this is the right answer, thanks!